# EFI Partition vs /boot in UEFI System

Tags: boot, uefi, gpt

I have a HDD Momentus Thin (500GB) + mSATA Samsung (32GB) and I intend to install Ubuntu 13.04 in a UEFI - GPT - Secure Boot - Linux only System.

I'll set the "/" (root partition) to use the whole 500GB HDD (dev/sda) and I'll partition the mSATA (dev/sdb) like this:

- sdb1 = EFI Partition (300MB)
- sdb2 = SWAP (8GB)
- sdb3 = EXT4 Volume (rest)

**My question is:** Do I need a "/boot" (Boot partition) even though my system is UEFI and I've already created an EFI Partition?

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need an additional, separate, /boot partition. /boot will reside on / on sda and that is fine.

Comment: So, the system will always have a "/boot" partition even if I have an UEFI PC + EFI Partition? In performance view, is it better to let the "/boot" reside on "/" in HDD or the best way is to create a separated "/boot" in the mSATA?

Comment: Your system will always have a /boot directory. The directory can be on a separate partition and mounted at /boot or not. There is no need for a separate /boot partition unless you are using LVM or encryption (luks) or some RAID

Comment: Thanks, I'll separete the "/boot", because I intend to encrypt the "/" and Swap using LUKS. I should point the "Device for boot loader installation" asked in Ubuntu's installation to the EFI partition (/dev/sdb1)?

Comment: Correction: I should point the "Device for boot loader installation" asked in Ubuntu's installation to the EFI partition (/dev/sdb1) OR to the "/boot" partition?

Comment: Probably /dev/sda

Comment: @Juan You may want have a look at how [Gummiboot](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/BootLoaderSpec/). It suggests storing the kernel images on the ESP (requires a larger ESP - 500 MB), eliminating the need for a separate boot partition. Unfortunately Gummiboot is currently not in the repositories and you would also need a script that generates the corresponding loader entries. I'd really wish that all of this was already in the repositories.